# Module Parse Failed: Unexpected token in Webpack Typescript Loader

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gulp, webpack, ts-loader

Trying to build a Typescript project using ts-loader for webpack within gulp. Getting the following error:

stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^
 Error: ./app/react/helloDirective.tsx
Module parse failed: C:...\app\react\helloDirective.tsx Unexpected token (1:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:13)
    at Parser.pp.raise (C:...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:923:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1490:8)
    at Parser.pp.expectContextual (C:...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1449:39)
    at Parser.pp.parseImport (C:...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2254:10)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (C:...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1762:60)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (C:...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1666:21)
    at Parser.parse (C:...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1632:17)
    at Object.parse (C:...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:885:44)
    at Parser.parse (C:...\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock. (C:...\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "target": "ES5",
        "moduleResolution": "classic",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true
},
"exclude": ["node_modules", "typedefinitions"]
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('compileReactApp', function(){
return gulp.src(["app/react/helloDirective.tsx"])
.pipe(webpack({
    debug: true,  
      output: {
        filename: "reactapp.js"
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.(tsx|ts|js)$/, loaders: ['ts-loader'], include:["app"], exclude: ["node_modules"]}
        ]
      }})
).pipe(gulp.dest("./generated/"));
});
```

helloDirective.tsx

```
import React = require('react');
import ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import Hello = require("./hello.react");

App.Common.commonModule.directive("ReactHello", () => {
return {
    link(scope: any, element: any): void {
        ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, element);
        element.on('$destroy', () => {

        });
    }
}
});
```

hello.react.tsx

```
"use strict";
import React = require("react");

class Hello extends React.Component<any, any> {
render() {
    return <div>
        <span>Hello World!</span>
    </div>; 
}
}

export = Hello;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awesome-typescript-loader supports the allowJs option. ts-loader has plans to support it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think ts-loader only transforms for typescript. To transform es6 and jsx syntax you will need to add [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) to your webpack config.